# Error While updating Table using Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to update a table in a server(ServerA) using a linked share connection from ServerB and i Got the below Error

> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "ServerA" could not
>   UPDATE table "**[ServerA].[MyDb].[dbo].[tbl_name]**" because of column
>   "CreateDt". Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the
>   data type used by the provider.

This is the query I Used :

```
update [ServerA].[MyDb].[dbo].[tbl_name]  
set transfer_fl = 1, 
    CreateDt = getdate()  
where transfer_fl<>'1'
```

the column **CreateDt is of data type smalldatetime** and it already has a value in it.

Can somebody give explain me why this happens.

Comment: i don't have much ideal but below link seems helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388927/conversion-failed-due-to-data-overflow-numeric

Comment: Are your server and linked server both Sql Server?

Comment: Yes. Both of them are on SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Is transfer_fl interger `1` or string `'1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in SQL 2008/R2.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/430745/sql-server-2008-unexpected-behavior-when-inserting-datetime-value-in-smalldatetime-column-on-a-linked-server

Unluckily it is marked as won't fix and you would have to do an explicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

[GETDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188383(v=sql.120).aspx)

Sintaxis

```
GETDATE ( )
```

Tipo de valor devuelto

```
datetime
```

no smalldatetime

Here is more detail explain of the [SQL Server Error Messages - Msg 298](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-298.aspx)

Comment: `GETDATE()` can actually be assigned to a smalldatetime field. you could try to assign it to a smalldatetime variable in SSMS. Even your link said that dates outside of 1900-2079 will pose problem. The problem only happens on linked server in SQL2008.